# Is there a software for converting the digit photograph to inbetweening effect?

Tags: photography

Is there a software for converting the digit photograph to inbetweening effect?

I mean, if I use digit camera take a picture of scene, whether there is a software can convert it to a picture like freehand sketching?

The digit photo:

[image]

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Prisma app](https://prisma-ai.com) for smartphones, it has lots of such filters, for instance "Curly Hair"
[image: orig]
[image: filtered]

Answer (score 0):

I use the combination of [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) & [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) with results like:
[image: the results]

- [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) is a Free, Gratis & Open Source, Cross Platform photo editing program that has 100s of photo manipulation options and filters.
- [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) is also a Free, Gratis & Open Source, Cross Platform tool which can be installed as a standalone program or as a plugin filter within Gimp. The current version gives over 500 filters, some simple and some with lots of options.

The above result was obtained by copying your original from the web browser, going to Gimp, selecting Create From Clipboard then Filter, G'MIC, Artistic, Pen Drawing and not playing with the settings.

[image: G'IMC in action]
[image: GIMP 2]

I also gave the G'MIC Colored Pencils Filter a go an played with the settings a little to get:
[image: Colored Pencils Filter]

Comment: The result is very unlike my expectation.

Comment: Steve, OP didn't want "some artificial effects" but the image "stretched". While I don't believe there's something creating "image b" from "image A" (as B has several details added), I vaguely remember Gimp having some stretching algorithm to "widen" parts of the image while leaving other parts untouched.

Comment: @aircraft Playing with the parameters in the various tools can make a huge difference to the results.

Comment: Oh, *sketching* … I've read "stretching", and the pictures supported that very much (compare the "house behind", and see the second "nipple" on the foreground roof). Sorry then. Shall we remove related comments then?

Comment: Happy to remove!

Comment: @Izzy - Well, I think the confusion is completely warranted, since I really can't figure out what the OP is asking for. Yes, they used the word "sketching" in their question, but they also said "inbetweening effect" and I have no idea what that means. The sample images that OP provided did not help me understand at all; if anything, they made me more confused. The 2nd image is not only "drawn-looking" but the proportions and details have changed. If those are significant, that's beyond what any image filter can do, even in principle.

Comment: @Izzy - The changes of the relative proportions in the drawn 2nd image could have subtly nudged you toward the idea of "stretching", since some elements have been stretched, in some sense. For all I know, OP means [inbetweening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbetweening), in the sense of having automatically generated transition images that will give the effect of a smooth transformation of the 1st image into the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

For instant and reasonable results I have two suggestions (in seperate answers):

[Photo Sketch Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aerotools.photo.sketch.maker.editor) by Aero Tool from Google Play Store - there are more than a couple of dozen preset (and adjustable) choices, here are three:

[image: Photo Sketch Maker Example]

Answer (score 0):

For instant and reasonable results I have two suggestions (in seperate answers):

[Sketch Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.pixelab.sketch) by Pixelab from Google Play Store - there are more than a couple of dozen preset (and adjustable) choices, here are three:

[image: Sketch Camera Example]

The added bonus of Sketch Camera is not only can it transform existing photos but it can apply it's effects to your phone's camera in still and video mode.